# Finding links on page matching HREF pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, screen-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

I am trying to interact with a website full of images and want to interact with it by clicking on each image. Each image has a relative url (eg: /image/1000/, image/1023/, etc). The number I assume is the image_id and appears to be random, not in consecutive order.

This is what I did in rails console:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get('http://www.website.com')
agent.page.links_with(:href => '/image')
```

The last line did not return anything but when I tried

```
agent.page.link_with(:href => '/image/1000/')
```

It returns the link as expected.

I am pretty sure the problem is in the :href parameter, it should not be '/image'. But i tried other combinations like '/image/' , '/image/* ', etc and it still return nothing.

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: untested

Try: `agent.page.links_with(:href => /\/image\/(\d{1,})/)`. The links_with documentation shows a regexp being used so I assume this will work fine. Also, `$1` will return your `image_id`.

http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page.html#method-i-links_with-28criteria-29

Comment: Note that `\d{1,}` is the same as `\d+` (but uglier) ;) Further, I might suggest using the `%r` regex literal so that you don't have to escape your slashes: `:href => %r{^/image/(\d+)}`